# Change data to numeric type to determine which distribution fits better

Tags: r, vector, dataframe

I am trying to figure out which distribution fits best logarithmic stock returns. Here is my code:

```
library(TTR)
sign="^GSPC"
start=19900101
end=20160101
x <- getYahooData(sign, start = start, end = end, freq = "daily")
x$logret <- log(x$Close) - lag(log(x$Close))
x=x[,6]
```

I want to use the function `descdist(x, discrete = FALSE)` which I got from this amazing post https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/132652/how-to-determine-which-distribution-fits-my-data-best Nonetheless r gives me this error: `Error in descdist(x, discrete = FALSE) : data must be a numeric vector` How do I transform my data to numeric vector??

The output from `dput(head(x))` is:

```
structure(c(NA, -0.00258888580664607, -0.00865029791190164, -0.00980414107803274, 
0.00450431207515223, -0.011856706127011), class = c("xts", "zoo"
), .indexCLASS = "Date", .indexTZ = "UTC", tclass = "Date", tzone = "UTC", index = structure(c(631238400, 
631324800, 631411200, 631497600, 631756800, 631843200), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), .Dim = c(6L, 
1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, "logret"))
```

Comment: What does `class(x[,6])` return? What does `class(x$Close)` return? Do the values "look" numeric?

Comment: `x$logret <- log(x$Close) - lag(log(x$Close))` is the logarithmic return of the stock closing price. That would be `ln(price2/price1)` .  `class(x[,6])` is the 6th column which is the column where the logarithmic data of interest is. @MrFlick

Comment: That's what you expect, but I asked specifically what `class()` will return on those objects. I'm trying to see which might not be numeric and `class()` is the best way to do that.

Comment: OP, it might be useful if you copy-and-paste the output from `dput(head(x))` in your question, to help us understand your data.

Comment: `> class(x)
[1] "xts" "zoo"` @MrFlick

Comment: Try `descdist(as.numeric(na.omit(x)), discrete = FALSE)`.

Comment: Worked like a charm @WeihuangWong thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pre-process `x` using `as.numeric(na.omit(x))`, or simply run

```
descdist(as.numeric(na.omit(x)), discrete = FALSE)
```

Comment: I seem to even need the `as.numeric` even if x is already numeric...  Very odd, but thanls for the answer!